# Ignore exceptions in node_modules when debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a Node.JS project running in Visual Studio 2017. The debugger often breaks due to exceptions occurring inside other modules, like Express. In most cases, the exceptions never bubble into my code, as they are expected and caught.

My question therefore is, how do I configure Visual Studio to not break on exceptions that occur in files stored in `node_modules` directory.

I looked in `Options - Debugging` and `Options - Node.js Tools` but there's nothing. I also tried to use condition in Exception settings, that doesn't work either:

[image]

I also have enabled Just my code, that also does not help at all:

[image]

Comment: How about use Exception Settings to ignore those exceptions, Debug->Windows->Exception Settings (CTRL+ALT+E)?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Most of the exceptions are of type `Error`, I don't see how could I ignore them in foreign code only.

Comment: It seems that this should work only for CLR exceptions.